# grub does not recognise specially-formatted ext4 partition

Tags: grub2, ext4, mkfs

As the title states, `grub` is unable to recognise my ext4 partition:

```
                        GNU GRUB  version 2.06-3~deb11u5

   Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
   lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
   device or file completions.


grub> ls (hd0
Possible partitions are:

Device hd0: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size
2097152KiB
        Partition hd0,gpt1: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at
131072KiB - Total size 1966063.5KiB
        ...
```

The disk is using GPT partitioning scheme and the bootloader is the default EFI GRUB2 (`grub-efi-amd64-signed`) shipped with Debian 11. The partition contains a Linux installation cloned from another disk with `rsync -ahPHAXx` (as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/709176)) (however GRUB doesn't recognise it even when the partition is empty).

On another Linux installation, I am able to mount and browse the above mentioned filesystem and no errors are reported by e2fsck either: `/dev/sdb1: clean, 25991/122880 files, 176823/491515 blocks`

This ext4 partition has been formatted using the following command:

```
sudo mkfs.ext4 -v -o 'Linux' -O '^has_journal,resize_inode,^filetype,^64bit,sparse_super2,^huge_file,extra_isize,inline_data' -E 'resize=8388608,root_owner=0:0' -M '/' /dev/sdXY
```

This issue first occurred on a virtual machine. However, I tried to replicate the same setup on a physical machine by creating a partition of the same size on an existing GPT disk and formatting it with the same options, and trying to `ls` the disk with different versions of EFI GRUB2 shipped with different distros (CentOS, openSUSE etc.) but always got the same issue (`No known filesystem detected`).

Can someone point out which of the specified options passed to `mkfs` is causing the partition not to be recognised by GRUB, but causing no issues in mounting and using on a booted Linux?

Comment: It would be interesting (just out of curiosity) to know how much space is actually saved by the use of `inline_data` vs without on your filesystem?  This only applies to files/dirs of a few hundred bytes, so would save at most one 4KB block per file. For a separate boot partition it would be almost nothing, but for a root partition it might be a few hundred MB (maybe $0.10 on a modern drive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GRUB2 doesn't currently support the `inline_data` ext4 feature.

I can't say for sure whether you can disable it at runtime using tune2fs (on an unmounted partition) but you could try.

Comment: It isn't possible to disable `inline_data` on a filesystem where files have used this feature to store data inside the inode.  This would only happen for files/dirs of a few hundred bytes. Given that this is a clone of another filesystem, the easiest solution would be to reformat without this option and make a new copy.